# input accessory view on button click

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

I have two text field and a button in a view. In button click I want the keyboard to show up and take a pin number.
I want to create a view like the following.

[image]

I've tried but could not get anything like that. How can I make something like this?

Comment: You Should add four text field with and Add accessor view to all four textfield

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
- (IBAction)clickButton 
{
    [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I think you could not understand the problem. The text field is in accessor view. At first the user can not see this textfield. He/she will see the other two textfield. When they press submit then this textfield with keyboard will be show.

Comment: Do you want a textField that will go along with the keyboard?

Comment: yes something like that. But I don't want to let the user see that textfield before keyboard showing up.

Comment: Ok, for this you should use inputAccessoryView in your textField. InputAccessoryView will show with keyboard, it will look natural.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is not tested.but you can do like this

```
 - (IBAction)clickButton 
{
    [self createInputAccessoryView];
    [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

 -(void)createInputAccessoryView{

    UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);

    UITextField *txtFeild1=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
     UITextField *txtFeild2=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
     UITextField *txtFeild3=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
     UITextField *txtFeild4=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:rect];

    [keyboardToolbar addSubview:txtFeild1];
    [keyboardToolbar addSubview:txtFeild2];
    [keyboardToolbar addSubview:txtFeild3];
    [keyboardToolbar addSubview:txtFeild4];

     [txtFeild1 setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
    [txtFeild2 setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
    [txtFeild3 setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
    [txtFeild4 setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];

}
```

Comment: One thing, I don't want to the user to see these field at first, these will be shown when the user press a button. But I could do so. I had to set input accessoryview in viewDidLoad. I can not do it in button click. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: this will show if you write becomeFirstResponder for any textFeild. so in viewdidload dont use becomeFirstResponder

Comment: Not working, I don't have a textfiled to becomeFirstResponder. I was planing to show the keyboard on click. and the data will be inserted in AccessoryView textfield and on return key press I will receive the data.

Comment: keyboard shown? if it is then definitely you had used the becomeFirstResponder. debug the code

Comment: Okay, i know but I don't have a text field. I want to take input in accessoryview textfield. So how can I use becomeFirstResponder??

Comment: on click txtFeild1 will becomeFirstResponder. nd u can see the accessor view on the keyboard.